# how to develop/connect to a SQL Server that uses Windows authentication?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I have a macbook running OSX. But at the same time I am developing an Windows console-based C# application. I am doing development/unit testing on a Windows7 virtualbox.

I can connect fine to a SQL Server database as long as a user is created for me. This is fine while on development. We are ready to do a full test now simulating a production environment and creating a user is not possible as our production SQL servers uses Windows authentication.

My problem is that I cannot connect to an ActiveDirectory server while using virtualbox. So I'm thinking of installing Visual Studio on the server and reconfiguring my datasources and compiling the code again. I don't have access to a Windows machine sadly.

Is this the correct/right way to do it? If not, then please enlighten me. :)

Thanks

Comment: "Is this the correct/right way to do it?" - Absolutely NO!

Answer (score 0):

I take it you will use 2 separate Windows machines during the test - one with the application and another with the server, right?

If that's the case, all you need to do is to create a Windows user on each of them, with the same login AND password. If the group security policy isn't set to "paranoia" level on either of these machines (i.e., any kind of NTLM authentication is allowed for network), you can use SSPI in your connection strings.

Oh, yes, and don't forget to give that user all the permissions necessary within the SQL Server.

Comment: I'm planning to install Visual Studio on the same server where SQL Server resides.

Comment: @mrjayviper, in this case it's even easier - just make sure that the Winodws user under which the application (or Visual Studio, for that matter) will be run has appropriate permissions in SQL Server.

Comment: are you suggesting I just go ahead and install visual studio on the server? thanks again

Comment: @mrjayviper, strictly speaking, no. If you have compiled binaries of your application, you may install only them. It depends on what you are expecting to do with the VS.

Comment: well when I compiled them on the windows vm, it is using a dedicated user acct on the SQL server. on production and real-world testing, I  must be using my corporate acct. and I can't use my corporate acct on a windows vm because it won't let me.